# Wald's approach to deriving the Einstein field equations and the Levi-Civita connection through Palatini's action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, action

I'm reading Appendix E of Wald's General Relativity book and I'm a bit confused in how he derives the Einstein field equations and the Levi-Civita connection through Palatini's action. The Palatini action he uses is the following:

\begin{equation}
S (g^{ab}, \nabla_a) = \int R_{ab} g^{ab} \sqrt{-g} \ \text{d}^4 x
\end{equation}

Where $R_{ab}$ depends solely on the connection and it's independent of the metric. I understand all the algebra he does afterwards to reach the following equation

$$\begin{align}
\delta S &= \int (C^{bd}_{\ \ \ d} \delta^a_{\ c} + C^d_{ \ dc} g^{ab} - 2 C^{b \ a}_{\ \ c}) \delta C^c_{\ ab} \sqrt{-g} \ \text{d}^4 x\\
&+ \int \Big(R_{ab} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{ab} \Big) \delta g^{ab} \sqrt{-g} \ \text{d}^4 x
\end{align}\tag{E.1.21}$$

Where $C^c_{ \ ab}$ is the difference between the Levi-Civita connection $\tilde{\nabla}_a$ and our arbitrary connection $\nabla_a$. He then argues that in order for $\delta S / \delta C^c_{\ ab}$ to vanish, the terms inside the parentheses need to vanish when symmetrized over $a$ and $b$ which implies that $C^c_{\ ab} = 0$, i.e. that $\nabla_a = \tilde{\nabla}_a$; while the vanishing of $\delta S / \delta g^{ab}$ leads to Einstein's field equations.

What I'm having a bit of trouble understanding is the reasoning he gives to prove that minimizing Palatini's action leads to the Levi-Civita connection. Why do the terms inside the parentheses need to be symmetrized over $a$ and $b$? How does this condition lead us to conclude that $C^c_{\ ab} = 0$? Isn't it already symmetrized over $a$ and $b$ since $C^c_{\ ab} = C^c_{\ ba}$?

Comment: @Qmechanic What I first thought of was that only the symmetric part over $a$ and $b$ of the terms inside the parentheses contribute to the contraction with $\delta C^c_{\ ab}$ since $\delta C^c_{\ ab} = \delta C^c_{\ ba}$. Was this what Wald meant?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: @Qmechanic Understood. Then I imagine that when we symmetrize these terms and equal them to $0$, we deduce that $C^c_{\ ab} = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  If you want to derive it yourself, you can show it by contracting $a$ with $c$ and then $b$ with $c$ in the quantity in parentheses.  The two resulting equations together imply that $C^{ad} {}_d = 0$ and $C^d {}_d {}^a = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP is right that Wald assumes that all connections are torsionfree, cf. point 5 on p. 31. Hence $C^c_{\ ab} = C^c_{\ ba}$.

As to why the terms inside the parentheses in eq. (E.1.21) need to be symmetrized over $a$ and $b$, consider the following analogy:

If $M^{ab}S_{ab}=0$ for all symmetric matrices $S_{ab}$, then we can only conclude that $M^{ab}=-M^{ba}$ is an antisymmetric matrix.